# Create a dynamic column with values that match a criteria - KQL

Tags: azure, kql, azure-log-analytics, azure-sentinel

I am trying to add values from a dynamic array of integers called `utfChars` to a new dynamic array called `suspiciousCharactersDetected` but only when they match a specific criteria.

The criteria is that if the value is in the range defined by the `suspiciousCharacters` variable then it should be in `suspiciousCharactersDetected` else nothing.

How would I do this?

Here is what I have tried so far. When I run this, it prints out all of the values in the dynamic array and not just the "suspicious" ones.

```
let suspiciousCharacters = range(126,1327,1);
datatable(Column1: dynamic)
[
    dynamic([1,2,3,4,5,150,160])
]
| where Column1 has_any (suspiciousCharacters)
//Missing something here?
| mv-expand suspiciousCharactersDetected = Column1 to typeof(int)
| summarize SuspiciousCharacterDetected=makeset(suspiciousCharactersDetected)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use the [`set_intersect()` function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/setintersectfunction).

for example:

```
let suspiciousCharacters = range(126, 1327, 1);
datatable(utfChars: dynamic)
[
    dynamic([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 150, 160]),
    dynamic([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 15, 16]),
    dynamic([1300, 1400, -1700])
]
| extend suspiciousCharactersDetected = set_intersect(suspiciousCharacters, utfChars)
| where array_length(suspiciousCharactersDetected) > 0
```

| utfChars | suspiciousCharactersDetected |
| --- | --- |
| [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 150, 160 ] | [ 150, 160 ] |
| [ 1300, 1400, -1700 ] | [ 1300 ] |

or, you could use the [`mv-apply` operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/mv-applyoperator), and the [`make_set()` aggregation function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/makeset-aggfunction).

for example:

```
let suspiciousCharacters = range(126, 1327, 1);
datatable(utfChars: dynamic)
[
    dynamic([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 150, 160]),
    dynamic([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 15, 16]),
    dynamic([1300, 1400, -1700])
]
| where utfChars has_any (suspiciousCharacters)
| mv-apply c = utfChars to typeof(int) on (
    where c in(suspiciousCharacters)
    | summarize suspiciousCharactersDetected = make_set(c)
)
```

| utfChars | suspiciousCharactersDetected |
| --- | --- |
| [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 150, 160 ] | [ 150, 160 ] |
| [ 1300, 1400, -1700 ] | [ 1300 ] |

Comment: Thank you, this is a great answer. I was trying to do the second one you showed but couldn't work it out. The first option is much cleaner though